# Parse .txt to csv and insert into database in php

Tags: php

code:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $filename = $_FILES['field']['name'];
        $path = "attandance_file/";
        $move = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['field']['tmp_name'],$path.$_FILES['field']['name']);
        $path_file = "attandance_file/".basename($_FILES['field']['name']);
        $fileObj = fopen( $path_file, "rt" );
        while (($line = fgets( $fileObj )))
        {
            $members = explode("\n", $line);
            foreach($members as $row)
            {
                $rowss = explode("  ",$row);
                foreach($rowss as $data)
                {
                    $query = "insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)values('".$data."')";
                    echo $query;
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

In this code I have upload a .txt file and then click on submit then read .txt file which is readable after that I used explode function to show view on new line but when I insert data into table and then print query it look like:

```
insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)values('No')
insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)values('TMNo')
insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)values('EnNo')
insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)values('Name')
insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)values('INOUT')
insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)values('Mode')
insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)values('DateTime')
```

But I want this

```
 insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)values('No','TMNo','EnNo','Name','INOUT','Mode','DateTime')
```

How can I do this ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: one way you could do is gather all the inputs first, then make a singular query after all is done

Comment: i don't think you need the second `foreach` loop, after the explode using the space, you can make the insertion from there

Comment: Yes actually I have use while (($row = fgetcsv( $fileObj, null, "\t" ))) @Ghost

Answer (score 1):

The way to do it is to use a database driver directly, and done so very easily.

In your code remove this:

```
foreach($rowss as $data){
  $query = "insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)values('".$data."')";
}
```

And change it to the following:

```
$sql = "insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)values(".trim(str_repeat('?,', count($rowss)),',').")";
```

Now your `$sql` string is ready to be used as a prepared statement in PDO or MySQLi and parse `$rowss` to the execute parameter like so:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
if(!$stmt->execute($rowss)){
  echo "Failed to execute query.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have all needed value of records?

```
$rowss = explode("  ",$row);
foreach($rowss as $data)
{
    $query = "insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)values('".$data."')";
    echo $query;
}
```

change to:

```
$query = "insert into attandance(No,TMNo,EnNo,Name,INOUT,Mode,DateTime)values('".str_replace(" ", "','", $row)."')";
echo $query;
```